# How redirect URL to to file In Cyberpanel and OpenLitespeed

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed, openlitespeed

How can I redirect URL to to file In Cyberpanel and OpenLitespeed?

`dl.mydomain.com/vid` to `mydomain.com/myfile.zip`

I used this code inside `/vide` directory, but is not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dl\.mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dl\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^vid\/?$ "https\:\/\/mydomain\.org\/myfile\.zip" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "but now working" - I assume that should be "not"!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `dl.example.com/vid` to `example.com/myfile.zip`

*Aside:* Note that if `/vid` is a physical directory then you should be requesting `/vid/` (with a trailing slash), otherwise mod_dir will issue a 301 redirect to first append the trailing slash.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. So, if "this code inside /vide directory" (although I assume you mean `/vid`?) then this should be omitted from the URL-path you are trying to match.

For example:

```
# /vid/.htaccess

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dl\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/myfile.zip [R=301,L]
```

Note that you used `.com` in your example, but `.org` in your rule. I'm assuming this should be `.com`.

There is no need for all the backslash-escapes in the *substitution string* (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive) - this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex (but even if it was, colons and slashes wouldn't need to be escaped). (This is very cPanel-esque).